# WSDL с вложенными параметрами

Tags: soap, wsdl

Вопрос простой: как объявить, что аргумент у запроса имеет не плоскую, а вложенную структуру?

В pojo параметры выглядят так:

```
public class Input {
    String DATE_FROM;
    String DATE_TO;
    List<ID> TASK_ID;
}
public class ID {
    String id;
}
```

Как построить такую же структуру в wsdl?

Сам тип SOAPа:

```
<xsd:complexType name="SOAP_INTERGATIONRequestType">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="SOAP_INTERGATIONRequestElement" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="DATE_FROM" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="14"/>
                  </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="DATE_TO" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="14"/>
                  </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="TASK_ID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="24"/>
                  </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Нужно заменить `TASK_ID` на список таких ИДшников.